# How can you insert VBA or any code into a csv?

Tags: vba, csv

I was able to make macros in excel and then run them when opening them. But when I save the file it doesnt save my macros.

How can I make a csv execute code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Many people wouldn't expect to open a `CSV` and have it run code. Make a script that reads the `CSV` and does what ever is needed. [PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/22/use-powershell-to-read-a-csv-file-and-create-active-directory-user-accounts.aspx) could be a good option here.

Comment: Presumably this is if you load it in excel, or would these macros work in other other office products?

Answer (score 1):

Comma Separated Values (CSV) is more or less a standard file format and is only plain text.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 for more information.

The reason people made different, more complicated file formats is because they wanted to store things (like code or formatting) that plain text doesn't support.

If you want to store code, you have to use a different file format.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the file as **.csv**, export your VBA into a set of **.bas** files.

When you open the **.csv** file, you can also import the saved **.bas** files into VBA as well.

Comment: No, this is too convoluted. Too many actions to perform..I need some code to run as soon as the application starts